# Correctly setup Passport Local

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the Passportjs documentation and understanding what should be used for creating users vs what is used to authenticate users from a login. It appears that my login post method is actually creating new users, but without an email. Should I use the `LocalStrategy` method in place of my `/sign-up` post method to create users?

Current Routing:

```
   var express = require('express');
    var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var models = require('../models/db-index');

    /*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/


    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField : 'password'
        },

        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
          }
          if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
          }
          return done(null, user);
        });
      }
    ));


    /*====  Index   ====*/

    siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/index.hbs');
    });

    /*====  Login   ====*/


    siteRoutes.route('/login')

        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('pages/login.hbs');
        })

        .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/app',
            failureRedirect: '/login'
        }));



    siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
        })

        .post(function(req, res){

            models.User.create({
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password
            }).then(function() { 
            res.redirect('/');
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
        })

    });








    module.exports = siteRoutes;
```

Comment: Can you define function `user.validPassword(password)`? Otherwise the LocalStrategy seems fine, but that function could be the reason of adding the new users without email.

Comment: This was a part of the documentation found here: http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password It seems like this is used as the password validation

Comment: The issue was with the form method. It was pointing to the wrong route